# How can i select an image from gallery and display that in another activity..?

Tags: java, android

i have created the code to select image from gallery,but i can not pass that value to another activity through bundle..please help me

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
            img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);


enter code here
```

i need to pass the `SelectedImageUri` to another activity as bundle

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                img.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
                Intent intent = new Intent(this , Second_activity.class );
                intent.putExtra("image_path", selectedImagePath);
                startActivity(intent);
}
```

it will start the Second Activity, then on the second Activity receive those values by this

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String value = extras.getString("image_path");
        //use value
    }
```

Comment: it fine.. but how can i add this bundle intent to another button click..i have a PLAY button i have to pass the selectedImagepath to another activity when this PLAY button is clicked...

Answer (score 0):

I know is not exactly what you were looking for but if you pass selectedImagePath using     `i.putExtra("photoPath", selectedImagePath);`, you can later load the image using only the path.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass the SelectedImageUri to another activity as bundle

=> FYI, Uri class itself implement Parcelable, so you can add and get value into/from Intent directly.

```
// Add a Uri instance to an Intent
intent.putExtra("SelectedImageUri", SelectedImageUri);

// Get a Uri from an Intent
Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra("SelectedImageUri");
```